# .NET: Can't simulate proper Facebook HTTP request with cookies

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, cookies, httprequest

I'm trying to download chat messages via *facebook.com/ajax/mercury/thread_info.php* with all the cookies and POST data it needs. (This is what supplies the messages when you click "Load older messages" on PC)

In C#.NET, I'm using [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to do the request.

I extract my cookies from Chrome's appdata, so every Facebook-related cookie is in the request, I checked it manually as well. I hardcoded the POST-data from the request, because I haven't figured out yet where it comes from, but that's not my question.

My problem is that the response from Facebook is that I'm not logged in. So I guess something's wrong with the cookies (or the other headers), but I absolutely don't know why. Or WebClient is not doing its work as I want it to?

I just don't understand, what can be the problem, while I'm reproducing the exact request. I have Facebook chat open in Chrome as well while testing. What am I missing?

Here's how I set the headers (cookies later):

```
var cli = new WebClient();

cli.Headers.Add("accept", "*/*");
cli.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "utf-8");
cli.Headers.Add("accept-language", "hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
cli.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
cli.Headers.Add("cookie", "");
cli.Headers.Add("origin", "https://www.facebook.com");
cli.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36");
cli.Headers.Add("x-msgr-region", "LLA");
```

Cookies:

```
string cookiesStr = "";

while (cookiesQuery.Read()) {

    // ... SQLite stuff ...
    // the query is:
    // SELECT name, value, encrypted_value FROM cookies WHERE host_key LIKE "%facebook%"

    cookiesStr += name + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(value) + "; ";

}

cli.Headers.Set("cookie", cookiesStr.Substring(0, cookiesStr.Length - 2));
```

As far as I can see, this works perfectly, so it gets the cookies and puts them in the string. I checked it, every cookie which is sent by Chrome when requesting *thread_info.php* is in the string.

Post:

```
NameValueCollection post = new NameValueCollection();

post.Add("messages[user_ids][...][offset]", "500");
post.Add("messages[user_ids][...][timestamp]", "...");
post.Add("messages[user_ids][...][limit]", "500");
post.Add("client", "web_messenger");
post.Add("__user", "...");
post.Add("__a", "1");
post.Add("__dyn", "...");
post.Add("__req", "ms");
post.Add("fb_dtsg", "...");
post.Add("ttstamp", "...");
post.Add("__rev", "...");
```

And the request:

```
byte[] r = cli.UploadValues("https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/thread_info.php?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT", "POST", post);
```

And it says I'm not logged in. But Facebook, I am me, I have the cookies, I have all the data you need, why don't you trust me?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Perhaps Facebook's servers know you're trying to scrape, and your requests are identifiable as not being a real user browser session?

Answer (score 0):

As Igy says, when you try to download chat messages, you'll need an access token. Create a developer account for facebook to develop an app and get an app id. Use the app id to get an access token, asking extended permission 'read_page_mailboxes'. Go to the Facebook for developers website to create an app: https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

I notice you try to get your inbox chat messages using the url endpoint 'thread_info.php'. This is used to get all messages within a specific conversation using a thread id (format example t_id.0000000.0000000). In order to get all your chat inbox messages - meaning all conversations with all messages in each conversation - you'll need to call the following url endpoint:'threadlist_info.php?__pc=EXP1%3ADEFAULT&dpr=1'.

Answer (score 0):

Ive done it with

```
        public string GetThread(string thread_fbid, long start, long end=0) 
    {
        //https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/thread_info.php?dpr=1
        //messages[user_ids][EXAMPLE][limit]=300&__user=EXAMPLE&__a=1&fb_dtsg=EXAMPLE

        if (end == 0) { end = start + 20; }
        if (end <= start) { end = start + end; }

        Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        data["messages[user_ids][" + thread_fbid + "][limit]"] = end.ToString();
        data["__user"] = c_user;
        data["__a"] = "1";
        data["fb_dtsg"] = fb_dtsg.Replace(":", "%3A");

        var resp = p.POST("https://www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/thread_info.php?dpr=1", data, UA, BaseURL);
        var str = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return str;
    }
```

Of course, you have to declare **c_user** and **fb_dtsg**, which you may obtain during the part of login. **p** is my class for doing posts and gets, you may use the HttpWebRequest for this, UA is the UserAgent which can be provided and with BaseURL i provide the URL "http://www.faceook.com/" for the referer